# How to fill the iphoneX notch with the ion-footer button color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, iphone-x

[image]

I have a button in the ion-footer, the code is below:

```
<ion-footer no-border>
  <ion-toolbar no-padding style="height:44px; width:100%;">  
    <button style="height:44px; width:100%; background-color:#FC111C; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;">Button</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

How to fill the red color of the whole bottom notch. thanks

Comment: This is Safe area. so you can not fill this. only you can fill it by coloring your self.view

Comment: @SandipGill thanks for your reply, how to do that?

Comment: are you using react?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a gap where the safe area inset is and I need to fill it with my footer's background color.